# strange behaviour of CoreData NsManagedObject

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am facing a very weird problem with coredata.
I have an item managed with ids and i'm trying to update a dynamic property which is a simple NSNumber. I do this as always, in my item class:

```
- (int) hits{
    return [self.hitNS intValue];
}

- (void) setHits:(int)h{
    self.hitNS=[NSNumber numberWithInt:h];
}
```

Basically, i create my managed, object with this method:

```
[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"item" 
    inManagedObjectContext:[self getManagedObjetContextForCurrentThread]];
```

Then I update my hits, after I receive some data from the server. 
CoreData tells me it updated the item, but when I access the item again:

```
-(NSArray *) getStoredEntities:(NSString*)entity withPredicate:(NSPredicate*)predicate 
{       
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc=[self getManagedObjetContextForCurrentThread];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:entity
        inManagedObjectContext:moc]];
    if (predicate)
        [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchResults = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; 
    [request release];
    return [fetchResults objectAtIndex:0];
}

Item *i=(Item*)[self getStoredEntity:@"Item" 
    withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(id==%@)", itemId]];
```

my property item.hits is not set to the new value, I get the old one.

What's driving me nuts is that When I kill my app, and start again, my object is there and it works well. If y update my hits count, I get the good value...

So I think my problem is in some way connected to the first insertion of my object in CoreData... 
Is there a cache I'm not seeing? Do I have to do something to "invalidate" my object?

Some help there would be really great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means your get/set managed contexts aren't synced.

After you save a context the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` is sent and all other contexts interested in these changes have to observe this notification and then use `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` to synchronize.